# How to use servlet to read id token after Azure AD login

Tags: azure, servlets, active-directory, jwt

A very simple situation:

- Azure webapp with AD authentication
- the redirect URI is an index.html static page.
- Open browser to http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/index.html
- redirect to AD login page. Users enter username / password.
- redirect back to http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/index.html

Now I want the landing page shows "Hello, [first name] [last name] !".  I know the first name, last name, and other info can be found in the id token after successfully login.
In chrome, I open the developer tool and start opening that URL. After I get to the index.html, I'm not able to find the id token in the request header in all network call.

I have servlet to dump all the request header data also cannot see the id-token.

So how can I get the id token from backend or even front end (javascript) ?

Yes I know I can use graph API to fetch user info. But if it is available in the token, I don't want to make extra call.

Comment: Just found out a way to do it...using the URL `xxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` can get the id_token, in which the family name, given name can be found.

Comment: Also, from server side the request header X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN will has this token as well.

Comment: It looks like that's a JWT.  Use a library such as [Auth0 JWT](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) and pull out whatever you configured on the AD side.